# How to add OAuth facebook login in Ionic v2 + angular v2?

Tags: facebook, oauth, angular, ionic2, facebook-authentication

I'm using the Ionic v2 for create an app and I now want to add Facebook /Google plus login API. I already implemented a Facebook login on my website using OAuth. But Now wanting to implement it in Ionic-2 application.

in simple want to implement register screen with Facebook in my app with

Like, 
[Click for understand more better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZF3C.jpg)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i implement this code but not working properly https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/use-ng2-cordova-oauth-for-all-your-ionic-2-oauth-needs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auth0 developer here.

Have you tried following this comprehensive tutorial? https://auth0.com/blog/ionic-2-authentication-how-to-secure-your-mobile-app-with-jwt/. It covers implementing Facebook and Google login for your Ionic 2 app.

You might also want to check out this https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/ionic2.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: I tried. but it is paid. i want free API that covers Facebook and Google login for your Ionic 2 app.  Thanks..

Comment: Actually, there is a free version that allows you to use 2 social identity providers. In your case, you can use Facebook and Google without paying for anything. Check this out [https://auth0.com/pricing](https://auth0.com/pricing) and if your app is open source, then you don't have to pay for anything.

Comment: Yes right, Up to 7,000 Regular Active Users per month it's free. Thanks.. @unicodeveloper...

Answer (score 0):

Finally i succeed in Facebook login API. i refer http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/facebook/  for the achiving this.

```
onFBLoginClick()
 {
   Facebook.login(['email']).then(data=>{
     this.faceBookToken=data.authResponse.accessToken;
     this.faceBookUserId=data.authResponse.userID;

     //Call getter function
     this.onGetDetailsClick();
   });
 }

 onGetDetailsClick()
 {
   Facebook.api(this.faceBookUserId+"/?fields=name,email,birthday,gender",['public_profile']).then(data=>{
     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   });
 }//onGetDetailsClick()
```

Thanks a lot IONIC Team...